# jQuery Validate: submitHandler submits form without hitting form.submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

jQuery Validate is working (triggers error when required email field is empty) but the code within submitHandler is not triggered (alert does not show). And since the submitHandler is not working I don't expect the form to be posting to secure/process_login.php, since form.submit(); is after after the not working alert() but it does if it validates.

Form Code:

```
<form action="secure/process_login.php" method="post" id="login_form" name="login_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Log In</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email"placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password">
      <input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Log In</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $("#login_form").validate({
  submitHandler: {
    function formhash(form, password) {
       // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
       var p = document.createElement("input");
       // Add the new element to our form.
       form.appendChild(p);
       p.name = "p";
       p.type = "hidden"
       p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
       // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
       password.value = "";
       // Finally submit the form.
       alert("Test");
       form.submit();
    }
  }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your JS. You don't need to wrap the formhash function in braces. Try this:

```
$("#login_form").validate({
    submitHandler: function formhash(form, password) {
        //submit code
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil. I changed it and tried again. The funny thing is that now the look and feel of validate changes (plain text vs a nice box). But the rest stays the same, the alert is not triggered and the form is posted anyway.

Comment: I copied your exact code, applied my fix and it ran locally for me. Without the fix, I saw a syntax error

Comment: Does your script tag come before or after your form HTML? If it is after your will need to wrap it in a $(document).ready(function() {})

Comment: You also get the alert before the form posts? I have exactly your code (with mine in it) but the alert does not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `loginform` as id attribute to the form tag. As you are using `$('#loginform')` as your selector.

Comment: Changing `<form action="secure/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">` to `<form action="secure/process_login.php" method="post" id="login_form" name="login_form">` results in the same behaviour.